# Initialize std::array without constexpr

Tags: c++

```
void test(const std::size_t& x) {
    std::array<std::string, x> arr;
}
```

When I compile the above code I get this error.

main.cpp: In function ‘void test(std::size_t&)’:
main.cpp:15:24: error: ‘x’ is not a constant expression

How can I get the above code to compile?

Comment: What is the reason that you try to use `std::array` instead of `std::vector` if the size is not a compile-time constant? That is pretty much the difference in use case between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template arguments must always be constant expressions, and function parameters are never constant expressions. To make this code work, you could do as is suggested in the comments and use `std::vector` instead, or you could make your `test` function be a template and make `x` be a template parameter instead of a function parameter.